# How to attach Visual Studio debugger to a process that loads dynamically?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dynamic, process, visual-studio-debugging

So I have this process that after trigger of a certain event gets closed as soon as it gets launched.
How do I attach debugger to these processes which run for not more than a few milliseconds or say 1-2 seconds.

This process is not a standalone process, it's a software that launches this process to achieve a particular task.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) allows Visual Studio to automatically debug child processes (new processes spawned from a process that you are already debugging).